# What is the highest possible level sharpness enchant on anything using /give?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a death torch and all the pvp-related enchants (protection, sharpness, knockback, etc.) are resetting themselves back to 0, so I'm pretty sure 10,000 is over whatever limit there is. Here's my command:

```
/give TheGuardianHound minecraft:redstone_torch 1 0 {display:{Name:"Ebolaids"},ench:[{id:1,lvl:10000},{id:2,lvl:10000},{id:3,lvl:10000},{id:4,lvl:10000},{id:5,lvl:10000},{id:6,lvl:10000},{id:7,lvl:10000},{id:8,lvl:10000},{id:16,lvl:10000},{id:17,lvl:10000},{id:18,lvl:10000},{id:19,lvl:10000},{id:20,lvl:10000},{id:21,lvl:10000},{id:32,lvl:10000},{id:33,lvl:10000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:10000},{id:48,lvl:10000},{id:49,lvl:10000},{id:50,lvl:10000},{id:51,lvl:10000},{id:61,lvl:10000},{id:62,lvl:10000}]}
```

Yeah. You can look up the enchantments [here.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment#Enchantments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highest level for any enchantment is level 32767.
[This is because when programming in C for java, the maximum value for an integer is 32767.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer)